# heroku rails app database migration issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise

I recently added devise confirmable module to my rails app. My application runs well in dev. But, when I push it to heroku, it says "We're sorry, but something went wrong.". Following is my heroku log-

```
Rendered devise/confirmations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.7ms)
2012-02-03T01:55:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Rendered devise/shared/_links.erb (0.5ms)
2012-02-03T01:55:07+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /users/confirmation/new] miss
2012-02-03T01:55:07+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 16.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2012-02-03T01:55:07+00:00 heroku[router]: GET personaldiary.herokuapp.com/users/confirmation/new dyno=web.1 queue=0 wait=0ms service=42ms status=200 bytes=1540
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/users/confirmation" for 50.131.164.83 at 2012-02-03 01:55:11 +0000
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"iVVTpWgIrBTR8b9k07lr2tYDFQfAYD0R8JmGVkmfzl4=", "user"=>{"email"=>"hrishikeshp19@gmail.com"}, "commit"=>"Resend confirmation instructions"}
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   Processing by Devise::ConfirmationsController#create as HTML
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0x000000023254e0>):
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]:   
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [POST /users/confirmation] invalidate, pass
2012-02-03T01:55:11+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

It is clear that the database does not have "confirmed_at" column. My migration file is as follows:

```
class AddConfirmableToDeviseV1 < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
   add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
   add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
   add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at , :datetime

   add_index  :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
  end

  def down
    remove_index  :users, :confirmation_token

    remove_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at
    remove_column :users, :confirmed_at
    remove_column :users, :confirmation_token
  end
end
```

My production is hosted on heroku:

So I ran

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It gave me no output.

Then I ran

```
heroku run rake db:rollback
```

It gave me

```
==  AddConfirmableToDeviseV1: reverting =======================================
-- remove_index(:users, :confirmation_token)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

Index name 'index_users_on_confirmation_token' on table 'users' does not exist

Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
```

Also,

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --trace
```

gives me following

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump
```

Any Ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you run db:migrate with --trace and see if any output ?

Comment: ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Invoke rails_env (first_time)
** Execute rails_env
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
** Invoke db:schema:dump (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:dump

Comment: Have you got multiple apps setup in Heroku ?

Comment: Are you using Postgres with Heroku ? Can you login to database and ensure that the latest migration in the schema_migrations table is equal or less that the migration you generated ?

Comment: could the downvoter mind to give the reason for a downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I deleted my migration files. Added a new migration file with devise helper in migration change method.

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        change_table(:users) do |t|
            t.confirmable
        end
        add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    end
end
```

Ran the migration again with

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

And whoa...it worked. I do not know how does this make sense, but I am glad that it worked. Please leave comments, I am keen to read explanation.

Anyway, thanks everybody.

Comment: I am not sure but, it seems heroku does not support up and down methods. Could anyone please confirm this.

Answer (score 1):

You will definitely need to make sure your migrations have been run against the production database.

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

This presumes that your local environment can access the production database of course.

(Note: this is a generic comment - not a heroku specific answer - "heroku run rake db:migrate" is apparently the correct way to run migrations against production Heroku environment)

Comment: I ran rake db:migrate. It gave me nothing. I ran rake db:rollback. It says. Index name 'index_users_on_confirmation_token' on table 'users' does not exist

Comment: This won't be needed because Heroku should default to production, and it replaces your database.yml with their own